# How to consume SOAP API in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, soap

I am using Springboot framwork and eclipse.
I have schemas xsd and wsdl files for the related service.
I created the JAXB classes from xsd and wsdl.

What will be the best approach for consuming the Soap xml web service in Java. Please find the Postman request.
Thanks

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ xmlns:ns=http://service.bi.com/entity/message/2003/ xmlns:ns1=http://service.bi.com/provider/bi/biService/findBIDoc/2003/>
   <soapenv:Header>
      <ns:BIContext>
          <messageId>89</messageId>
          <creationTimestamp>2018-07-27T03:56:56.449Z</creationTimestamp>
          <hostName>localhost</hostName>       
      </ns:BIContext>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns1:findBIDocRequest>
         <ns:Version>13</ns:Version>
         <docNumber>789999</docNumber>
         <userId>test</userId>
         <readOnly>true</readOnly>
        </ns1:findBIDocRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

---

```
wsimport -keep -verbose http://example.com/yourwsdl?wsdl
```

---

```
import org.springframework.ws.client.core.support.WebServiceGatewaySupport;

public class SoapClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

public Object callWebService(String url, Object request){
    return getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(url, request);
}
```

### }

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class YourService {

    @Autowired
    private SoapClient soapClient;

    public Object callSoapService() {
        Object request = new Object();
        return soapClient.callWebService("http://example.com/soapApi", request);
    }
}
```

---

```
@Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        // Set this to the package name of your generated domain objects
        marshaller.setContextPath("com.example.soapclient");
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();
        webServiceTemplate.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        webServiceTemplate.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        // Configure other properties as needed
        return webServiceTemplate;
    }
```

---

```
// Construct the request object
        Object request = new Object(); // Replace with your actual request object
        String endpointUrl = "http://example.com/soapService";

        // Send the SOAP request
        Object response = soapClient.callWebService(endpointUrl, request);

        // Process the response as needed
```

Comment: Thanks. Where to write the <dependency> tag. I have JAXB classes that are generated from xsd and wsdl schema. I need to create a POST method . Do I need to marshalling?

Comment: Thanks. Where to write the <dependency> tag. I have JAXB classes that are generated from xsd and wsdl schema. I need to create a POST method . Do I need to do marshaling?    What should be my steps?  I am creating the request object from the Request class that is created. How to add the header information in the Request? Header contains messageId, creationTimestamp, hostname. Create a request that contains request and header. Is it return xml or java object?

Comment: Please help how to consume Soap xml service in Java SpringFramework. I have jaxb   classes that are created from xsd and wsdl. What could be the steps of writing a POST method in Java?

Comment: ur using Jaxb2Marshaller?